# Winforms cast Control to other control type and assign specific event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

As for question I'm creating controls programmaticallya nd depending on variable I need to create different control types and then add them to a panel.

When I try to cast a CheckBox from a Control and add the `CheckedChanged` event, I get "Control does not contain a definition for that [...]".

I know I can just duplicate the `Panel.Add(Control)` line and avoid using a common control, but I was wondering if it is possible to correctly cast a control from a more generic Control

```
          Control val;
          if (dataType.Equals(COIL))
          {
            val = new CheckBox
            {
              Name = $"txt{i}"
            };
            val.CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;
          }
          else
          {
            val = new TextBox
            {
              Name = $"txt{i}",
              Size = new Size(70, 20),
              TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
              TabIndex = i
            };
          }

          flpValues.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { lbl, val });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### What is the problem?

You have code like this:

```
Control val;
// ...
val = new CheckBox
{
    Name = $"txt{i}"
};
val.CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;
```

It does not work because there is no `CheckedChanged` in `Control`, and `val` despite being `CheckBox` is typed as `Control`.

---

### How to fix it?

You could cast it:

```
Control val;
// ...
val = new CheckBox
{
    Name = $"txt{i}"
};
((CheckBox)val).CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;
```

However, in my opinion, that is doing unnecessary extra work. I'd use another variable instead:

```
Control val;
// ...
var checkBox = new CheckBox
{
    Name = $"txt{i}"
};
checkBox.CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;
val = checkBox;
```

In fact, that could easily extract those lines to another method, leaving you with:

```
Control val;
// ...
val = CreateCheckBox(i);
```

---

### Can you cast it safely?

Perhaps you are more interested in whether or not you can safely cast it. After all, when you write `((CheckBox)val)` the compiler does not check if the type is correct, instead that check happens at runtime (and throw if it fails, which won't happen).

There are a few ways to do safe casts, starting with `as`:

```
Control val;
// ...
val = new CheckBox
{
    Name = $"txt{i}"
};
(val as CheckBox).CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;
```

Now, depending on your analyzers, you could have a warning. Since casting with `as` will not throw, but may return null. Which would - in theory - result in an exception. Of course, we know that won't happen in case (so you can suppress any warnings, if you have them).

Another option would be to use `is`:

```
Control val;
// ...
val = new CheckBox
{
    Name = $"txt{i}"
};
if (val is CheckBox checkBox)
{
    checkBox.CheckedChanged += ChangeValue;   
}
```

Now I have introduced both a conditional statement (which we know will always be true) and a new variable. At least it has no warnings. However it should be evident that just having the additional variable as I first suggested is strictly better than this (since that solution has no conditional).

---

### Will the compiler optimize it?

Perhaps you worry about whether or not the compiler can optimize the code.

The code [`((CheckBox)val)`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+aAdjAARpkC8ZADANwCwAUCwMID2pCHGZAbhAxNmAelFkAdNJaC+NYnADuZNgAs4AYwDWAIQ4APFgG8WZc2QByEMHGpkAJACIYBmMbQBfJy08iAFP7qWnqGAJRyYZLBOnDY6hDEAOZxZHg0CclwAGpCAK5wIiwAAgAsqmqJKbkYBf4cwABWWuRQcMTYiEhkxQCMkgCi/O0wAIIISVBkEBNQYcaeJQBMqlwwPBjGxQDMPb20VjaFi8zFKzGhBiCr3Lxbu3DDpHuDTzAAEonYGIgVIXGZFLYeieIA==) will result in a `castclass` opcode. [`(val as CheckBox)`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+aAdjAARpkC8ZADANwCwAUCwMID2pCHGZAbhAxNmAelFkAdNJaC+NYnADuZNgAs4AYwDWAIQ4APFgG8WZc2QByEMHGpkAJACIYBmMbQBfJy08iAFHJk0KoaOvoGAJSS6lracNjqEMQA5glkeDRJqXAAakIArnAiLAACACyhyWn5GEX+HMAAVlrkUHDE2IhIZKUAjJIAovwdMACCCClQwZNQkcaeZQBMqlwwPBjGpQDMvX20VjbFi8ylK7HhhiCr3Lxbu3AjpHtDTzAAEsnYGIihcQnZNLYeieIA==) will result in a `isinst` opcode. Similarly [`if (val is CheckBox checkBox)`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+aAdjAARpkC8ZADANwCwAUCwMID2pCHGZAbhAxNmAelFkAdNJaC+NYnADuZNgAs4AYwDWAIQ4APFgG8WZc2QByEMHGpkAJACIYBmMbQBfJy08i0AGZkABRyFFCqGjr6BmSaUXqGAJQmZhbxWokGkuqZcNjqEMQA5vlkeDSFJXAAakIArnD0Fr4sLAACACyRRaV1GI3BHMAAVlrkUHDE2IhIZO0AjJIAovxTMACCCMURENtQScaeHQBMqlwwPBjG7QDM8wu0VjZNx8ztZ7nRhiDn3Lw3e5wNakB4rEEwAASRWwGEQkTyBTUvXy9E8QA===) will result in `isinst`, plus branching (I got `brfalse.s` in sharplab).

An not, the JIT compiler does not seem to optimize it either. In fact [the suggested solution](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+aAdjAARpkC8ZADANwCwAUCwMID2pCHGZAbhAxNmAelFkAdNJaCEZAMYALOAoDWAIQ4APamWJwA7mTYr1W7SwDeLMnbIA5CGDh6AJACIY2mFbQBfDxZ/EWVVTR1JU3C4bFMIYgBzWLI8GnikuAA1IQBXOBFBPhow8x0RFgABABYTJQTknIx8gAoOYAArVXIoOGJsRCQySoBGSQBRfj6YAEEERKgyCHmoAEorfyqAJhMuGB4MK0qAZmGR2kdnAs3mSp3osu0QXe5eI9O4KdIzia+YAAkEtgMIg6jE4vVMth6P4gA==) that uses a new variable does not have any opcodes related to casting or checking the type. It is also the shorter code in JIT asm.

Comment: Sweeb Baby Jesus and all the pharisees in the temple. I've never got such a complete,  perfect, and explicative answer. You, good Sir, just made me happy on so many levels. If we ever meet, I'll offer you a beer.